# Is ESP32-Pico D4 Kit able to charge batteries out of the box?

Tags: battery-charging, lifepo4, esp32

I was looking at this:

https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/ESP32-PICO-KIT/1904-1030-ND

I read somewhere that Dev boards like this have the ability to charge batteries (LiFePO4) when connected to USB and run of the batteries when not connected to USB.

Is this true? Does that mean that you just connect the battery to 3v3 & GND, and charge via USB? But then how will I know the charge level etc?

I tried going through the Datasheet, but couldn’t figure this out. There are a number of tutorials which describe how using an external module, you can charge the battery, but if there is already some circuitry built-in, I would prefer to use that to keep my footprint small.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: the getting started guide says that only one of the 3 mutually exclusive options (usb,3v3,5v), can be used at a time, so I guess the other poster was incorrect. If I’m wrong please let me know.

Comment: If you look at the schematic you will notice this particular dev board has no li-po charge controller.  So, no.  But there may be other larger esp32 dev boards that do have a charge controller and separate battery connectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lolin D32 board has an onboard charger.

[image]

> the module also includes a charging circuit for a single cell 3.7V
>   lithium battery, meaning that this module can easily be used in remote
>   applications.

But the one you are referring to 
, unfortunately not.